# What is the proper identifier to use when adding a keychain item using KeyChainItemWrapper?

Tags: objective-c, keychain, identifier, keychainitemwrapper

I don't really understand what the identifier is or how it is used.

Is it arbitrary?  Is it my app name in reverse?
Below I use "test" but should it be: "com.mydomain.myApp.test"?
Or my app bundle identifier:  "com.Soundpaper.soundpaper.fakeID123"?
Or what?

Thank you.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) KeychainItemWrapper *myChain;
    
     . . .

if (myChain == nil)
{
    // first question: what identifier should I use?        
    myChain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"test" accessGroup:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KeychainItemWrapper is a wrapper class to hide all the CFRef conversion stuff from the "typical" developer.
Being so, all the "rules" of the Keychain services in the *Security* framework hold.

Therefore, whenever you access a keychain item, the framework will automatically "add" the bundle id of your app to that item, to ensure that you can read only your own items, see e.g. [SecItemAdd discussion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1401659-secitemadd?language=occ#discussion).

Hence, the `identifier` is completely arbitrary and may only raise conflicts within your own app, not with others.

**Remark:** if you specify an `accessGroup`, you can share keys between apps, see [Sharing Access to Keychain Items Among a Collection of Apps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps?language=occ)

Comment: Thank you.  I am aware of your other points, but the one that really answered my question is: "Hence, the identifier is completely arbitrary and may only raise conflicts within your own app, not with others." 

That's what I was looking for. Thank you again.